# Как отобразить script Bitrix в компонент Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите как отобразить скрипт в компоненте vue?

```html
<template>
 <section class="form mb-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper-page mb-8">
            <h2>Свяжись с нами</h2>
        </div>
        <script data-b24-form="inline/22/icm5ig" data-skip-moving="true">
(function(w,d,u){
var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=true;s.src=u+'?'+(Date.now()/180000|0);
var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
})(window,document,'https://--------/upload/crm/form/-------');
</script>
    </div>
 </section>
</template>
```

Вставлял просто, но он не отображается

Comment: Vue не разрешает помещать скрипты внутрь шаблона. Воспользуйтесь хуком mounted.